# JQuery Validation Engine and primefaces commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jquery-validate, facelets, primefaces

I am currently having some trouble using my client side validation. I am using the Jquery Validation Engine plugin and I can't get it to work with PrimeFaces commandButton.
I think the problem is that the primefaces commandButton isn't a normal submit button like you have using  and now my question is how do I get it to work so that when I click on  my client side validation is triggered, cause using only server side validation is something I want to avoid for the user experience.

The page I want to use it on is dynamically include through a  but that doesn't cause the problem according to me.

I am using JSF 2.0 with Facelets and PrimeFaces 3.0M1 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

`$("#buttonId").click(functionName);`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers :D

Answer (score 4):

Just let JSF validate by Ajax. Add a `<f:ajax>` or `<p:ajax>` which processes the current input field and re-renders the associated message when the `blur` event fires (when you tab out the field, e.g.).

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="fooMessage" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="fooMessage" for="foo" />
```

No need to duplicate/takeover the validation by jQuery.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Glassifish](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html) - Also covers Ajax based validation

Answer (score 2):

It turns out to be pretty simple
Just add handling for your p:commandButton onclick event

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['forecast']}" onclick="validator.validate();" update="somegrid" actionListener="#{someBean.someAction}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
```

And then just regular JQuery validator code

```
var validator = null;
$(document).ready(function () { 
    validator = $("form[id='forecastinput']").validate({ 
    //rules, messages, etc. 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the markup of the Primefaces command button you will see it uses the button tag with a type of "submit" by default.

`<button type="submit" style="height: 22px; line-height: 22px; font-size: 10px ! important;" onclick="PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest('/webapp/admin/listBadges.xhtml',{formId:'AddBadgesForm',async:false,global:true,source:'AddBadgesForm:j_idt54',process:'@all',update:'listBadgesForm:badgeList AddBadgesForm'});return false;" name="AddBadgesForm:j_idt54" id="AddBadgesForm:j_idt54" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon icoIDAdd"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp; Add Badge</span></button>`

This is just an example of what you would see.  Noting that, I am not sure how one would use Jquery validation on a button like this.  As far as the user experience is considered however the server side validation is all done through AJAX so it is transparent to the user.  I feel your reasoning for avoiding this is unjust unless your reasoning really is that performance is a huge concern or that visually it doesn't meet your business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

JSF won't work out of the box with JQuery validate plugin.

You must tweak it to make it work. This is because JSF posts forms using AJAX and not the default form.post method.

Use this to chain jquery validation when posting with h:commandlink and h:commandbutton:

```
//executes code before running default onclick behavior
//@param domId dom element id for the object which onclick method is being intercepted
//@param code a function holding the code to run before executing the original onclick method. This function should return true if original method is to be performed
function triggerBeforeOnClick(domId, code){
    if(document.getElementById){
        var commandLink = document.getElementById(domId);
        var commandLinkOnClick = commandLink.onclick;
        commandLink.onclick = function(){
            if(code()){
                return commandLinkOnClick();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

replace domId with

> 'formId:commandLinkIDOrCommandButtonID'

Make sure you use it within `$(document).ready(function( ... ));` and after having loaded jquery and validate libraries.

You must also specify validation rules for each input field by hand (disregard jquery docs on this matter) like this:

```
$(document.getElementById('formId:inputId')).rules('add', {
      required: true
      , messages: {
         required: 'error message'
      }
});
```